# Change DIV size using JavaScript not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscript

I wanted to automatically resize the my fixed div menu bar when someone scrolls down the page. I found a working example online of what I wanted(see jsfiddle below).

http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUB/4/

I then tried to implement it to my project.. but it didn't work. Scrolling down did not resize the div as anticipated.

Here is the code above combined with my menu bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynq8etnj/

Also, I'm not sure if I am importing this correctly (it's been awhile since I touched anything web related coding)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

I tried taking the jsfiddle I posted first and replicating on my pc then opening it in the browser and it didn't work like it did on jsfiddle.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your fiddle don't work because you are not including jQuery. [Working here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ynq8etnj/1/).

Comment: Ah thanks man!, now just to figure out why it wont run in the web browser o.o

Comment: What is your use case for this? This looks like a terrible UI design and I'm interested in why you want this functionality, if you don't mind answering. I'd be interested in seeing a valid use case for this.

Comment: Hello fellow, I can't help to see how your animation is clumsy when you continue to scroll down while the animation is running. This is because you're stopping it whit every scroll event. To fix this only add a flag to know if you already ran the animation. Here is the example. http://jsfiddle.net/ee9ftfbL/ Have a nice programming fellow.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I noticed that in the fiddle as well and thought it was just the fiddle being buggy. Probably wouldn't have been able to find a solution for that for awhile. Thanks again man.

Comment: @Sinistralis I've actually seen this used frequently on a couple of websites and I like the idea of it. The menu bar starts of at about 100px with large company logo and/or company name, then shrinks down to a smaller size along with the menu bar, about 30-45px. 

The home page will contain most of the information and will scroll down a long way, kinda of like the Apple product pages.

The size reduced menu bar will always remain at the top. So when someone scrolls down 5-6 pages, they don't have to click a "Top" button or scroll back to the top to use menu bar. It's always there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check out those pages. I tend to hate navbars that work like this because it obstructs vision of the page, but that is completely subjective.

Comment: @Sinistralis, That's were shrinking the menu bar on scroll event comes in play! :D

Here is a better done example. http://www.apple.com/watch/

I don't know if its just me, but I have noticed websites becoming less clickly-clicky and more scrolly-scrolly. Probably due to the increase of smart phones, tablets, and touch screens in the past few years.

I like it. It's cleaner and simpler. Sucks for me though, because I don't know much JavaScript. Creating a website is becoming harder and harder it seems. It use to be just HTML/CSS. Now to compete with other websites you need PHP, JS, JQuery, etc

Comment: I prefer swipe triggered menus or site designs that do not become too vertical. I cannot stand when nav bars overlap content.

Unfortunately, most mobile browser apps use swipes for menus already :/.

Also ew PHP :p. Anyway, this is getting too offtopic. Thanks for providing a use case. It might come in handy one day if a customer ever wants this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the older version of jquery Or you dont have include jquery library. Please include latest jquery.

Here is the updated version :  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

**Demo**

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
 'use strict';
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>45){
            // animate fixed div to small size:
            $('#nav').stop().animate({ height: 45},100);
        } else {
            //  animate fixed div to original size
            $('#nav').stop().animate({ height: 60},100);
        }
    });
```

```css
body { 
 overflow-y: scroll; 
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0; 
 font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
 font-color: #5C5C3D;
 font-size: 10px; 
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 height: 2000px;
 }

#nav { 
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: thin solid #5C5C3D; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%;
 top: 0; 
 }
 
#nav-menu {
 bottom:0px;
 height:60px;
 width: 960px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 background: url('images/logo2.png') no-repeat bottom left;
 text-align: right;
 }
#nav ul{ list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#nav ul li{ display: inline-block; }
#nav ul li:hover{ background-color: #333; }
#nav ul li a,visited{ color: #5C5C3D; display: block; padding: 15px; text-decoration: none; }

#wrapper{ width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; }
#content{ background-color: #FFF; border: 3px solid #DDD; padding: 20px; margin: 80px 0 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
            <div id="nav-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PARTNERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <h3>This is a heading!</h3>
                <p>You're learning how to create a fixed horizontal navigation menu!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank Bhavin! It works just like intended now. Much much appreciated bro.